# MAC OSX Xcode 9.2 linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, xcode9.2

Im having compiling issues with Xcode which gives the following error:

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please advise. 
Im really a noob to running codes here on Mac OSX so will appreciate all the help i can get.

Thanks,
Nishi
[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9kmC.jpg)

Comment: 1. Don't post images of code 2. Don't post links to code. Provide a [mcve] instead

Answer (score 0):

You have two `main` functions defined in `main.cpp` and `prog1.cpp`. Remove the file `main.cpp` from your project.